# How to defined a array list in props and data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In my project, I use vue.js.

I want to display content of list with nested loop。 In parent page, i have defined:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <detail-header></detail-header>
      ......
     <detail-list></detail-list>
  </div>
</template>
```

The component of detail-list is :

```
<template>
<div>
  <div v-for="(item, index) of list" :key="index">
  <div class="item-title border-bottom">
    <span class="item-title-icon"></span>
    {{item.title}}
  </div>
  <div v-if="item.children" class="item-children">
    <detail-list :list="item.children"></detail-list>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'DetailList',
    props: {
      list: Array
    },
   data () {
     return {
       list: [{
       title: 'adult',
       children: [{title: 'threePeople',children: [{ title: 'threePeople-w'}]}, {title: 'fivePeople'}]
       }, {
       title: 'student'
       }, {
       title: 'child'
       }, {
       title: 'offer'
       }]
    }
   } 
  }
</script>
```

unlucky, I got a error message:

```
Duplicated key 'list' of list: [{ in detail-list
```

who can help me ?

Comment: Do you have the only one `detail-list` on the page?

Comment: You have a prop named `list` and a data named `list`. There is a collision. If you're not passing any prop to the `DetailList` component, remove the `list` from `props`.

Comment: @Thoomas, remove the list from props, I can not get children content. Just title content can be  displayed.

Comment: @Igor, yes, only one detail-list in my paraent page

Comment: @stack This is because `list` is not a prop anymore, so `list` is not given to the `detail-list` component. If you want this to work, keep the `list` in props  (remove it from data) and define in your parent page's data. So the first `DetailList` and its children will have the `list` as a prop.

Comment: @tony19, a data named list is defined for my data. and a prop named list for displaying loop nested content

Comment: @Thoomas, yes, You are right!!

Comment: @tony19, yes. I already resolved this issue as Thoomas said

Comment: @stack Great ! I've written it as an answer :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to work, keep the `list` in props (and remove it from `DetailList`'s data) and define in your parent page's data.

So the first `DetailList` and its children will have the `list` as a prop.

So you'll have in the parent page :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <detail-header></detail-header>
      ......
     <detail-list :list="list"></detail-list>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Parent',
    data () {
     return {
       list: [{ ... the list ... }]
     }
    }
```